# Assertions with conditions

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, assertions

I would like to know if it is possible to use asser annotation with conditions.

Using symfony2, in my entity class, on one property I would like to put :

```
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
```

if another property has 7 as a value.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can utilize [Callback Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)

It could look like this:

```
class YourEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        if(($this->firstAttr == 7) && empty($this->secondAttr)) {
            $context->buildViolation('Second can\'t be empty when first is 7!')
                ->atPath('secondAttr')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make an [external callback validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#external-callbacks-and-closures) which may be even more suitable since it won't make any mess in you model code (entities).